# Is it possible to have nested models instead of master detail, loopback?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, loopbackjs, loopback

Is it possible to make or build model which contain a model in itself?
I build something like the fallowing  but is not what i want really. I know how to make it in master detail in SQL databases or noSQL.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "plural": "tests",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fam": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "tests":{
      "testname":{
      "type": "string"
    },
    "score":{
      "type": "string"
    }
}
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

But in `explorer` shown like fallowing to `POST` or `GET` data:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "fam": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "tests": {},
  "id": "string"
}
```

Comment: why do you think this is good idea?

Comment: I don't know this is good or bad idea I want to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a hasMany/belongTo relations(one-to-many) within the json. Make sure you define the foreign key. E.g: I define a person model, have relations defined like this:

```
"person": {
  "type": "embedsMany",
  "model": "person",
  "foreignKey": "boss"
},
"person": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "person",
  "foreignKey": "boss"
}
```

You should see an extra GET /person/{id}/person method within the explorer that returns which person belongs to which person(boss).